# Rails 5 routing error for assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So my app appears to be using the assets I have but I keep getting routing errors in my logs. The pages however seem to work when I load them. Not sure why. I've tried a number of different things. Do I need to require my css files in application.css.scss? It's also occurring with some JS files as well. I'm not sure what else to provide here either. I've only seen this in rails 5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you send GET respose to this file. You just need to require it to application.css.scss

skeleton Index.html contains absolute path to this css. Perhaps this cause the error.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
```

As a variant try to use skeleton-rails gem instead

Comment: No idea. Thats what I was wondering. I've never had to require all my custom files in pre rails 5 apps and I've never got routing errors. At least, not like this. I'll try requiring said files and see what happens.

Comment: Ill try the gem and let you know what happens. The weird thing here is the page is actually loading the assets. It looks fine on the surface. The logs seem to indicate something is off.